# Excel 2007 VBA, TimeSerial Function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a VBA script for Excel 2007.

Why does TimeSerial(0, -10, 0) return 0:10:00?

I use TimeSerial to substract minutes from a time, so it works in all cases. For example TimeSerial(23,-10,0) correctly returns 22:50.

But when my time is TimeSerial(0, -10, 0), shouldn't it return 23:50:00?

Comment: Not positive, but I don't think TimeSerial wraps around. What happens when you try `TimeSerial(23, 70, 0)`? I'd bet you don't end up with 0:10:0 either.

Comment: You do not have a date component and you cannot have negative time. Personally, I would rather see it throw an error but I guess this is the [TimeSerial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws25fd2z.aspx) function's way of providing a 'best guess' result. The `TimeSerial(23,-10,0)` works because taking 10 minutes away from 23 hours does not produce a negative result. @KenWhite - Actually you arrive at `12/31/1899 12:10:00 AM`.

Comment: @Jeeped: I guess I win that bet. :-) Yes, I'm familiar with the base date for COM/VBA. I wanted the poster to discover it.

Comment: Well finally I ended up using Format(DateAdd("n", -10, MyTime), "hh:mm"), MyTime is 00:00

Answer (score 0):

`TimeSerial Function` returns a `Variant/Date` value, which in the case of `TimeSerial(0, -10, 0)` is *negative*

The result of `TimeSerial(0, -10, 0)` as shown in the `Local Window` or when printed in the `Immediate Window` looks *positive* same as `TimeSerial(0, 10, 0)` *(try in the immediate window)*:

`debug.Print "TimeSerial(0, -10, 0) = " TimeSerial(0, -10, 0) vblf _
    "TimeSerial(0,  10, 0) = " TimeSerial(0, 10, 0)`

However a simple test using `IF` confirms:

a)  They are different *(try in the immediate window)*:

`debug.Print TimeSerial(0, -10, 0) = TimeSerial(0, 10, 0)`

b)  The negative value of `TimeSerial(0, -10, 0)`  *(try in the immediate window)*:

`debug.Print TimeSerial(0, -10, 0)  < 0`

To obtain `23:50:00` could use:

`debug.Print TimeSerial(24, -10, 0)` or

`debug.Print TimeSerial(24, -9, -60)` among others

For additional information see:
[TimeSerial Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251654(v=office.15).aspx) and 
[Data Type Summary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251528.aspx) and

Comment: I cannot use 24 because the user enters time 00:00 in the Excel cell

Comment: It seems that your question **"But when my time is TimeSerial(0, -10, 0), shouldn't it return 23:50:00?"** has been answered.
Now you are stating another problem. Suggest to accept this answer and create a new question, clearly stating in full details the problem.